# how to create weblogic domain using cargo plugin?

Tags: maven, weblogic, cargo

Can we able to create weblogic domain using cargo plugin? I know we can do it using maven-weblogic-plugin but to get benefits of cargo can we do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Cargo allows you to create WebLogic domain.

To create domain use [standalone local configuration](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Standalone+Local+Configuration.html) , as containerId use one of WebLogic identifiers. List of supported WebLogic versions with links to page with details can be found on homepage of Cargo project in left menu, for example [WebLogic12.2](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/WebLogic+12.2.x.html).